# How to add LINQ requests in list models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Good new everyone. I have model that have two list in two other models.

```
public class PersonalPageModel
{
    public List<USERS> list_Users { get; set; }
    public List<PERSONAL_INF> list_PersonalInf { get; set; }

    public string ChangePasswordErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Новый пароль")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to do LINQ requests and add results in combined model. After that will show in view page.
I did the requests and got result in details variables.

```
public ActionResult PersonalPage()
    {
        PersonalPageModel personalPageModel = new PersonalPageModel();

        personalPageModel.ChangePasswordErrorMessage = "Новый пароль совпадает со старым!";

        int iIdUsers =  Convert.ToInt32(Session["iIdUsers"].ToString());

        var personalInfDetails = dbModel.PERSONAL_INF.Where(model=>
        model.fk_iIdUser == iIdUsers).ToList();

        var userDetails = dbModel.USERS.Where(model =>
        model.iIdUsers == iIdUsers).ToList();

        personalPageModel.list_Users = new List<USERS>();
        personalPageModel.list_PersonalInf = new List<PERSONAL_INF>();

        return View("~/Views/Home/PersonalPage.cshtml", personalPageModel);
    }
```

But, I don't know how to add details variables in model lists. How to add?

View page code:

```
@model NarkomApp.Models.PersonalPageModel

@if (Model != null)
        {
            <table border="0">

                @foreach (var personalInf in Model.list_PersonalInf)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Город:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>ФИО:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vFIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Индекс:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vIndex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Населенный пункт:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(personalInf.vLocality, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Улица:</p></td>
                        <
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vStreet, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Дом/корпус/строение:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vHome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Квартира:</p></td>
                        <
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vApartment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Телефон:</p></td>
                        <td>@Html.Label(@personalInf.vPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                @foreach (var users in Model.list_Users)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Старый пароль:</p></td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Editor(Model.NewPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessage(Model.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Новый пароль:</p></td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Editor(@users.vPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessage(@users.vPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Подтвердите пароль:</p></td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Editor(@users.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })<br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessage(@users.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>

        } @* End if *@
        else
        {
            <h2>Проблема с сессией, пустой объект!</h2>
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to use personalPageModel.list_Users.AddRange(userDetails) before returning your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
personalPageModel.list_Users = new List<USERS>();
personalPageModel.list_PersonalInf = new List<PERSONAL_INF>();
```

just:

```
personalPageModel.list_Users = personalInfDetails;
personalPageModel.list_PersonalInf = userDetails;
```